# Wrong pip location in VSCode when doing SSH Remote

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

When running on my local machine (Ubuntu), VSCode terminal's paths are all correct.

```
(base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ conda activate reid2
(reid2) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ which python
/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin/python
(reid2) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ which pip
/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin/pip
(reid2) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ echo $PATH
/home/vinhtq115/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin:/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/condabin:/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

However, when I use SSH Remote with the said machine on my Mac, the path of `pip` is incorrect, causing it to install packages in wrong location. It appears that for some reason, `.local/bin` path shows up before environment's `bin` folder in VSCode SSH Remote. In addition, when opening a terminal in VSCode, aside from my chosen environment (already chose with Python: Select Interpreter), the `base` environment also appears next to it as well.

```
(reid2) (base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ which python
/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin/python
(reid2) (base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ which pip
/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin/pip
(reid2) (base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ echo $PATH
/home/vinhtq115/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/remote-cli:/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.pyenv/shims:/home/vinhtq115/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin:/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin:/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/condabin:/home/vinhtq115/.cargo/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/cuda-12.1/bin:/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.local/bin:/home/vinhtq115/.vscode-server/bin/0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Is there anyway to fix this? For now, I have to do `conda deactivate` twice and reactivate the environment I need to use the correct `pip`.

```
(reid2) (base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ conda deactivate
(base) (base) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ conda deactivate
vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ conda activate reid2
(reid2) vinhtq115@vinh-linux-pc:~/Projects$ which pip
/home/vinhtq115/miniconda3/envs/reid2/bin/pip
```

My terminal `settings.json`:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {},
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
}
```